# Why are we using thread&locks if we could use something more high-level?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

I was just introduced to concurrent programming, and I learned that locks are one of the simplest synchronization primitive and people almost always get it wrong.

My question is: why aren't they rather using something like promises(dataflow variables), csp, actors, etc all the time? Wouldn't that save us from bugs and deadlocks? Cannot all locks be replaced by that?

Comment: Because these high-level abstractions are not ideal.  They tend to be too expensive, too restrictive or make it harder to debug logical mistakes.  We're all waiting for the Einstein of software engineering to show up some day.

Answer (score 0):

Other problems are livelocks, race conditions and lack of parallelism. All concurrency models suffer from a few of these to different degrees.

Locks are just one tool in the toolbox. They have their sweet spot, so do have the other models.

The more you think about concurrency models the more you recognize how similar they really are. For example, actors plus message passing are like one lock per actor and the additional rule that you can only take one lock at a time. Clearly, that guarantees freedom of deadlocks and per-actor data races but it does not provide global correctness.

Comment: so we cannot say that actors are less error-prone than locks?

Comment: In some use cases they are less error prone, in some more. Pick the right tool for the job.

Comment: oh. We were told that they are a definitive solution to everything, now it makes more sense.

Comment: If that was true you could just make the entire application a single actor and be done... It's not that easy.